# Unable to find audio stream

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, directshow, avisynth

I'm trying to adapt a code in order to add a sound capture feature (on a live stream), with the help of ffmpeg and directshow.

When i try to play with ffplay the AVIsynth file, everything works perfectly i've got the audio and video. But when i open this input file by code i only find the video stream.

The Avs file :

```
V = DirectShowSource("Decklink_HDMI.grf", fps=10, framecount=1000000000, seek=false, audio=false)
A = DirectShowSource("Decklink_Audio.grf", fps=1, framecount=1000000000, video=false)
AudioDub(V, A)
```

The opening code :

```
ffmpeg::AVInputFormat * ifmt;

ifmt = ffmpeg::av_find_input_format("avs");

// Open input file
 if(ffmpeg::avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, filename.toStdString().c_str(), ifmt, NULL) != 0)
```

When i make a variable lookout on gdb just after the opening.

i'm looking at nb_streams in pFormatCtx->nb_streams and it's at 1
The only stream i can find in pFormatCtx->stream is a video one. And that's why i'm not able to capture the sound.

So i'm asking if i'm doing something wrong with my opening or if i miss something.

Ps : I know the code shown is short but the problem appears at this very step !

Thank you

Kurt

-- EDIT --

I've also noticed that when I dump the AVFormatContext the video stream got a 456x32 size.
And i can find this very same size of the window displayed when i try to launch a corrupted script with ffplay.

The original video format when i play the correct script with ffplay is of 1920x1080

I think my problem is maybe deeper than the simple fact of not being able to get the audio stream.

I'm trying to find out how to know the error message that is displayed on this 456x32 windows

-- EDIT2 --

I Find out what is written on this image and my problem is solved, badly placed avs script an old one was is place.

I'm ashamed.

Comment: If pFormatCtx->nb_streams == 1, then you have only one stream in that file.

Comment: That's right coyotee but when i play this file on ffplay or with virtual dub i can check their is clearly 2 streams and i can hear the sound so the avs file contain without a doubt 2 streams

Comment: Can you upload some short example of that file? I mean, you can also build ffplay and step through the code to see how ffplay does it...

Comment: You'r right but i've already done that, and i didn't find something special.

Comment: You probably missed something. Playing audio has to come from somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad,

A badly placed avs file was my problem.

Anyway ffmpeg is a bit painful in his way of showing error, being forced to make a snapshot without any error msg or exception raised (or maybe did i failled).